# Submenu disappears behind parent menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, overlay, z-index

I am having trouble with my submenu. It's a simple drop down menu that I have beside my posts and I got it working and all. The problem is that depending on my scroll position, it will sometimes reach the bottom of my screen. I was thinking about making something similar to the menus of http://9gag.com where the menus are fixed in 50% of the screen. But I guess that would be too complicated.

I tried to set the parent menu z-index to a lower value but it didn't work? I'd be thankful for any help.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HyKuR/

```
.Post .Bottom .nav { 
                            display: block;
                            line-height: 24px;
                            font-weight: bold;
                            margin: -140px 450px 0px; 
                            position: absolute;
                            z-index:2;
                            }

                     .Post .Bottom .nav li.submenu ul { 
                           visibility:hidden;
                           -webkit-padding-start: 0 !important;
                            margin-left: 40px;
                            margin-top: -215px;
                            bottom:100%;
                            background-color: white; 
                            border:1px solid gray;

                             }
                    .Post .Bottom .nav li.submenu:hover ul {
                             visibility: visible }


                    .Post .Bottom .nav li.submenu  ul li { 
                             border-bottom:1px solid gray
                             z-index:10 !important;
                            }
```

Comment: It will be easier for us if you make a JSfiddle with some html so we can help you, because with only the CSS you are giving us only the clothes, but we still don't know how the girl who wears them looks like. :)

Comment: Thanks, I learnt that now :) the girl metaphor was nice, here's the http://jsfiddle.net/HyKuR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As drip says give us your code in a jsfiddle so we can help. But from the top of my head I'd say your problem is down to your position:absolute on both menus. You should use position:relative on the parent menu then use position:absolute on the submenu so that it is placed based on the parent menu rather than the screen.

Comment: I avoided that solution because it messed up my other contents. But I fixed that and your answer worked :) thanks!